# AngularJS - Ionic - Parse - PayPal plugin : How to pass values to the buy function

Tags: angularjs, cordova, paypal, parse-platform, ionic-framework

hi i am trying to get a basic paypal payment setup within ionic. The products are loaded from a parse.com database all have an attached buy button. what i would like to do is pass the values from the products to the buy function. here is what i have now finally working using the example docs from the paypal cordova plugin.

the buy function within index.js

```
 buy : function () {
    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(PayPalApp.createPayment(), PayPalApp.onSuccesfulPayment,
    PayPalApp.onUserCanceled);
 }
```

the createPayment function thats called from the buy function

```
 createPayment: function() {
    // for simplicity use predefined amount
    var paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails("50.00", "0.00", "0.00");
    var payment = new PayPalPayment("50.00", "USD", "Awesome Sauce", "Sale", paymentDetails);
    return payment;
 }
```

the controller

```
.controller('PayPalCtrl', function($scope, ParseData) {
   // Open the login modal
   $scope.buy = function() {
   PayPalApp.buy();
   };  
})
```

html

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in items.results">
          <ion-item>
              <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
              <p>{{item.price | currency}}</p>
              <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="buy()">
                  Buy Now
              </button>
          </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Use this gist as a starting point:

https://gist.github.com/Urbiwanus/c1e456f889f53e940a11

Also remember to include the helper file in your index.html, under cordova.js, like so:

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<!-- No need to copy paypal-mobile-js-helper.js to js directory -->
<!-- ionic build android will put it in the platforms/android/assets/www/js directory -->
<script src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Then execute:

```
$ ionic build android
```

...if your platform is Android.